# Questions about the two addons folders in Odoo

Tags: odoo

In the Odoo project in GitHub I can see two different 'addons' folders. One in root. The second is in 'odoo/addons'

What are them for?

When I start Odoo with:

```
python3 odoo-bin --addons-path=addons
```

which one is referenced? I suppose the root one, but not completely sure.

Is necessary to declare in 'addons-path' the path to the folder 'addons' in root (--addons-path=addons), or odoo automatically detects and include it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `odoo/Addons` will automatically be added to the list of addons.

If you specify `--addons-path`, Odoo will search the folder for modules, and in this case addons will not be added unless you specify it.